# Sitecore 7 Custom Experience Buttons Missing

Tags: sitecore

Not sure why but I am not seeing the 'Applications' folder under 'Content'. All the tutorials out there mention editing the (/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Custom Experience Button) items to accomplish what I need.

My guess is I don't have view access to the core database in order to see these items or folders? If this isn't the case, how would I go about finding these buttons? Any help appreciated and I apologize if I didn't provide enough info but my goal is to add features to the page editor component toolbars.

Comment: If you login to desktop, can you switch to core database using database icon in lower right? if so, do so then re-open content manager.

Comment: Thank you! Completely forgot about Desktop mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this a formal answer...

First, login to desktop mode (on login screen, select "Desktop" from "Options" expander below form). Next, change database to core at bottom right:

[image: Sitecore change database]

Finally, re-open your content manager and you should see the `/sitecore/content/Applications` node.